# Spring Roo/STS: ServiceImpl method is not visible in Controller class

Tags: java, interface, spring-roo

I have the Roo-generated project in STS and try to customise update/delete methods to work with MongoDB (for cascade update and delete). I created service methods to update (delete) childs when the parent is updated (deleted):

```
 public class NoteServiceImpl implements NoteService {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public void updateNotesWithNoteBook(Notebook notebook) {
        Update update = new Update().set("notebook.name", notebook.getName())
                .set("notebook.author", notebook.getAuthor());

        Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("notebook._id").is(
                new ObjectId(notebook.getId().toString(16))));
        mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Note.class);
    }
...the similar for delete action
```

NoteService interface is Roo-generated and looks as follows:

```
@RooService(domainTypes = { org.dp.mongo.shortnotes.domain.Note.class })
public interface NoteService {
}
```

Than I made push-in refactor of update and detete methods from Roo controller*.aj of the parent entity Notebook to the Notebook controller class, and added calls to the child' service methods:

```
@RequestMapping("/notebooks")
@Controller
@RooWebScaffold(path = "notebooks", formBackingObject = Notebook.class)
public class NotebookController {
    @Autowired
    private NoteService noteService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "text/html")
    public String update(@Valid Notebook notebook, BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            populateEditForm(uiModel, notebook);
            return "notebooks/update";
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        notebookService.updateNotebook(notebook);
        **noteService.updateNotesWithNoteBook(notebook);**
        return "redirect:/notebooks/"
                + encodeUrlPathSegment(notebook.getId().toString(),
                        httpServletRequest);
    }

    the similar for delete method...
```

And finally got errors that noteService doesn't have method updateNotesWithNoteBook and delete method. How to fix them?

Answer (score 0):

Does the method updateNotesWithNoteBook exist in the NoteService interface?

You must to put it in the interface, that is what you're calling from the Controller.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did it and tried to put an answer, but couldn't cause my reputation level)